# CSS Selector for matching substring

Tags: css, selenium, css-selectors

I have a CSS Selector like this `span[label='./cakes/item1/./linkText']` where only this item number is varying. I want to write a common CSS selector that will work on any range of numbers

I have already gone through this tutorial but no luck.
https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors

I have tried:

`span[label*='./cakes/item_/./linkText']`

Comment: `span[label*='./cakes/item_/./linkText']` how long of the value of this label is common for other items? `./cakes/` till this? or this `./cakes/item` ?

Comment: I meant **common from starting of the value**

Comment: In entire CSS, only the item number is changing. E.g. `span[label='./cakes/item1/./linkText']` and `span[label='./cakes/item2/./linkText']` and `span[label='./cakes/item3/./linkText']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should select what you want by combinign the "begins with" and "ends with" wildcarding:

```
span[label^='./cakes/item'][label$='/./linkText']
```

Comment: It is not working but if I write it like `span[label$='/./linkText'][label^='./cakes/item']` then it works. What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `span[label^='./cakes/item']`

It should work for all the `span`s that have a `label` attribute with a value that begins with `./cakes/item` here is an example

```html
<style>
    span[label^='./cakes/item'] {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 25px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        background: #333;
    }
</style>

<span label="./cakes/item1/./linkText"></span>
<span label="./cakes/item2/./linkText"></span>
<span label="./cakes/item3/./linkText"></span>
<span label="./cakes/item4/./linkText"></span>
<span label="./cakes/item5/./linkText"></span>
```

Comment: It is not working. It is passing for `span[label^='./cakes/item1'/linkUrl]` too.

Comment: what did you use? this `span[label^='./cakes/item']` OR this `span[label^='./cakes/item1'/linkUrl]` ?

Comment: [This is the reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp), go through this, hope it would be helpful for you.